git clone in docker container results in error 8
Docker version 27.1.1, build 6312585 (from Docker's apt repository) on a fresh install of Kubuntu LTS 22.04.
Inside the container I am trying to clone the neovim repo to compile the code.
The Dockerfile FROM line is: FROM python:2.7.18
Yes, I know py 2.x! not negotiable environment from work to solve a problem and move to py3.
Here is what happens:
573.2 ++ git clone --progress https://github.com/neovim/neovim.git neovim
573.2 Cloning into 'neovim'...
576.1 remote: Enumerating objects: 255164, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.        
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
744.1 fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
744.1 fatal: early EOF
744.1 fatal: index-pack failed
744.1 ++ cd neovim
744.1 /scripts/root_neovim_compile_install.bash: line 48: cd: neovim: No such file or directory
744.1 ++ exit 1


Here is a list of configuration settings I tried:
# git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
# git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000  # Set buffer size to 500 MB
# git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0      # Disable low speed limit
# git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 999999  # Set low speed time limit to a large value
# git config --global core.compression 0
# git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 100M
2>&1 git clone --progress "https://github.com/neovim/neovim.git" neovim
# git config --global http.version HTTP/2

nothing works except... when executing the very same clone command into the host machine, the cloning process succeeds, so it's a problem related to docker or the way docker's networking works; the containers run in a custom network, if this is important:
sudo docker network ls
[...]
6f552b3d064d   name.network   bridge    local

What can I do?
